# Tomcat is running but 8080 port is not responding

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, port

I have installed sun `jdk 1.6 x64` and tomcat in a linux x64 machine through ssh, I don't have root privileges so I installed both in my home dir.

I managed to successful run tomcat but if I try to enter mydomain.com:8080 there's no answer from the server.

With this command:

```
netstat -atnp|grep LISTEN
```

I checked the port and it is LISTENING

```
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home2/fiegmund/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/server:/home2/fiegmund/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/amd64:/home2/fiegmund/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2015 ms
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home2/fiegmund/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/docs
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,869] milliseconds.
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home2/fiegmund/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/manager
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home2/fiegmund/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ROOT
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home2/fiegmund/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/examples
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home2/fiegmund/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/host-manager
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 18, 2011 5:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4582 ms>
```

Any ideas that what is the problem?

Comment: Does telnet from the local machine itself work?

Comment: Then it is likely that your hosting provider doesn't allow to listen on ports greater than 1024...

Comment: It runs fine for the very first time. Than after restart it hungs (port is listening and I can connect). Logs, blind config changes, strace, restarts - nothing helped. Than I took a break. When I came back I realized it's working ! I checked and it takes about 8 minutes to start [:oink:]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First step is to run telnet localhost 8080 when logged in locally.  Then type in something like

```
GET /
```

and you should get HTML back.
If that doesn't work, then tomcat is not really running properly or is not listening on port 8080.
If that works but when trying from outside, make sure that you have the correct ip address.  Try with ip address first.  If ip address works, perhaps your mydomain.com doesn't resolve to it.
If ip is correct (the same one you are ssh'ing to) and it still doesn' work, then you are probably running firewall which doesn't allow 8080 through.  Changing firewall configuration requires root access.

Comment: i forgot to tell that the server have already installed Apache http Server using port 80. Anyway, i tried with: lwp-request http://localhost:8080 and i got the html of apache tomcat...

Comment: I checked ports with netstat, and I got  :::8080 and 0.0.0.0:8080. Telnetting GET / it doesn't reply at all. I have good logs from web app startup. What should I check?

Answer (score 11):

The problem for me was that my Tomcat started listening to IPv6 ONLY. Putting it here in case somebody else finds out the same thing.

I was able to get proper responses with

```
curl -g -6 "http://[::1]:8080/"
```

But not with localhost.
To fix this, I *removed* `address` attribute from conf/server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
           address="0.0.0.0" />
```

and restarted and it bound to IPv4 again. I know it should be other way around, but this was what fixed it for me. OS was Ubuntu.

Comment: how did you find that it was running only on IPv6 ?

Comment: @JBD well, it bound only to ::1, but not to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 9):

Try to list out using following command on linux terminal TCP IP and port reference to the application like "java" as below.

```
[root@h5 ~]# netstat -ltnp | grep java -i --colour 
tcp        0      0 10.15.11.20:9990    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1626/java           
tcp        0      0 10.15.11.20:8080    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1626/java           
tcp        0      0 10.15.11.20:8443    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1626/java
```

Further first you need to check the open ports at the firewall.

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

If it is turn on and port is not there please allow the relevant port 8080 as below.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=8080
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 4):

On CentOs I had to open the firewall manually

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7999/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Not sure how, but if Docker was running a container on the same port, it would automatically open the firewall and so was throwing me off

Answer (score 0):

In case of war deployment if there is error in war file, tomcat may not be able to extract the war file. Make sure a folder having same name as war file is created in tomcat//libexec/webapps otherwise localhost:8080 will stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat may be too slow to start if one of the deployed applications is too slow to initialize. You can tell this is the case when you've started Tomcat, yet the browser says the server isn't responding, even though you can see that the port is listening (by connecting with telnet). Also note that your CPU usage may be too high. In my case, it was because I had enabled TRACE mode on the logger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try confirm the status of the server by running:

```
 lsof -i :8080
```

Answer (score -1):

[try this, it will solve the issue, Window -> Web browser -> Chrome. For external browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFyQi.png)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, please include the most important code in your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Close the IDE. Restart the process java.exe if you are on a windows system. And fire up the IDE after that.

Comment: This is not an IDE problem. OP clearly states that it's a Linux server with SSH access.