# Tomcat servlet works on local machine, breaks on server

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, websocket

I'm assuming I'm doing something simple and stupid since I'm new to this.  But I have a working Tomcat servlet.  On my local machine, when the connection is created with:

`var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/myapp/websocketendpoint");`

it works just fine.  In fact, I accidentally loaded it to the server with that and of course it still worked :P.

However, whenever I try to run the servlet on the server itself:

`var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://11.22.33.44:8080/myapp/websocketendpoint");`
it dies, saying that a connection cannot be established to the server.  To be honest, I used this [information](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-debian-9) to set up the server.

Comment: Make sure you are using the right port and that no firewall is blocking the action, furthermore, try change the ip address to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Yes, I briefly disabled the firewall.  I'll try 0.0.0.0 right now....

Comment: 0.0.0.0 just seems to connect the server to the localhost https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

Comment: yes, I thought that was what you were trying to achieve. If the servlet etc. is already running on the server and you can't connect to it, try diagnosing the problem with methods such as the ones shown on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554663/tomcat-running-but-8080-port-not-responding.

Comment: Thanks, I might even try to formulate a different question with that

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so hopefully this experience will help someone else.  Despite the estoric error message, I just needed to update my build.properties files... which is essence just updates the build.xml file.

So any errors over there can cause really strange errors it seems.